# Tracking onClick links not working as hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, onclick, tracking

```
<li><a href="konkurranseregler.html" onclick="javascript:kenshoo_conv('rules','0','','sem','NOK');return false;">KONKURRANSEREGLER</a></li>

<div class ="contactButton"> <a href="http://www.altavdrikke.no/#top" onclick="javascript:kenshoo_conv('kontakt','0','','sem','NOK');return false;"><span>Kontakta Oss</span></a></div>
```

These two buttons don't work as links, see: http://www.undergroundblc.co.uk/chaqwa/ i.e. you click but nothing happens. If you change 'return false' to 'return true' the buttons work again but no longer register with the tracking company. So my question is how do I keep 'return false' yet get them to work as links.

Comment: You may want to accept some answers to the questions you've posted - you'll get more interest from members in answering your new questions.

Comment: Have you checked that the javascript file that defines the `kenshoo_conv()` function is properly loaded?

Answer (score 0):

First of all. If you HAVE to have javascript embedded in your html (not recommended) you don't need to have the `javascript:` declaration in events (`onclick` in your example). It would be much better to use dom methods `el.addEventListener('click', kenshoo_conv, false)`.

If you need to fire a function before the page unloads you will need some control of that function to know when it has successfully fired the tracking becon.

Once you have your `onclick` attached, you can use the event argument (that is passed to the function) to stop the event from firing, `evt.preventDefault()`, do everything you need to do, then set the `location.href` when your tracker becon has successfully fired.

All up your code could look something like this (assuming everything is normalised, so not in IE):

HTML

```
<a href="konkurranseregler.html" data-args="rules,0,,sem,NOK"   
   class="kenshoo_conv_link">KONKURRANSEREGLER</a>
```

JAVSCRIPT

```
function kenshoo_conv(evt) {
    var dest = this.href,
        args = this.getAttribute('data-args').split(",");

    evt.preventDefault();

    //add success event to arguments
    args.push(function () {
       location.href = dest;
    });

    //fire the tracking function
    trackMe.apply(this, args);
}

var kenshoo_conv_links = document.getElementsByClassName("kenshoo_conv_link");
for (var i = 0, il = kenshoo_conv_links.length; i < il; i += 1) {
    kenshoo_conv_links[i].addEventListener('click', kenshoo_conv, false);
}
```

This will make the last argument in the trackMe function a callback to change the location to the destination of the link. So you'll have to fire that function once the tracker has successfully fired. If you don't know that, you could do it after a timeout (not ideal)